# Facebook on/off social reading in app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-social-plugins

I try social plugin "Recommendations Bar" and it works. It has a built-in function to activate and deactivate the social reading function.
I want to enable this function in my simple app with "read" publish_actions.
I don't want to use cookies or session var to do this, it's a wrong way.
Users have to choose in which article on/off the social reading and change his preference on the fly.

User login with:
scope="publish_actions, email"

I know:
$facebook->api("/me/permissions"); 
$facebook->api("/me/news.reads?limit=10");

and I can post reads: 
FB.api('/me/news.reads',
        'post',
        { 'article': 'xxxxxx',
        'access_token': 'xxxxx' },
        function(response)

and delete it:
FB.api(id, 'delete', function(response)

Any idea for API call to enable/disable social reading function?
How to set publish_actions permission value to 0/1 for the users having app installed?

Comment: And why storing the *user preferences* is a bad thing?

Answer (score 0):

> I dont want to use cookies or session var to do this, it's a wrong way.

Right, the user’s profile would be a better place to save this, so that he doesn’t have to make that decision again next time he visit’s your site.

> How to set publish_actions permission value to 0/1 for the users having app installed?

You can’t revoke permissions via app. And I can’t see why you would want to. If a user disabled social reading on your site (which you save in their profile, preferably), then just don’t post anything on their behalf.

Comment: I dont want to revoke permissions, I just want temporarily switch off !!!
In the same way I can do with Recommendations Bar plugin.